# reshaping data (a faster way)

Tags: r, data.table, plyr

I came across a table of freq. counts today I had to expand into a data frame of raw values.  I was able to do it but was wondering if there's a faster way using the reshape package or data.table?

**The original table looked like this:**

```
   i1 i2 i3 i4  m  f
1   0  0  0  0 22 29
2   1  0  0  0 30 50
3   0  1  0  0 13 15
4   0  0  1  0  1  6
5   1  1  0  0 24 67
6   1  0  1  0  5 12
7   0  1  1  0  1  2
8   1  1  1  0 10 22
9   0  0  0  1 10  7
10  1  0  0  1 27 30
11  0  1  0  1 14  4
12  0  0  1  1  1  0
13  1  1  0  1 54 63
14  1  0  1  1  8 10
15  0  1  1  1  8  6
16  1  1  1  1 57 51
```

**Here's an easy grab of the data using dput:**

```
dat <- structure(list(i1 = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L), i2 = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L), i3 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L), i4 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), m = c(22L, 30L, 
13L, 1L, 24L, 5L, 1L, 10L, 10L, 27L, 14L, 1L, 54L, 8L, 8L, 57L
), f = c(29L, 50L, 15L, 6L, 67L, 12L, 2L, 22L, 7L, 30L, 4L, 0L, 
63L, 10L, 6L, 51L)), .Names = c("i1", "i2", "i3", "i4", "m", 
"f"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -16L))
```

**My approach(s) to reshape the data (is there a faster way?):**

```
#step 1: method 1 (in this case binding and stacking uses less code than reshape)
dat2 <- data.frame(rbind(dat[,1:4], dat[, 1:4]), 
    sex = rep(c('m', 'f'), each=16),
    n = c(dat$m, dat$f))
dat2

#step 1: method 2    
dat3 <- reshape(dat, direction = "long", idvar = 1:4,
    varying = list(c("m", "f")),
    v.names = c("n"),
    timevar = "sex",
    times = c("m", "f"))
    rownames(dat3) <- 1:nrow(dat3)
    dat3 <- data.frame(dat3)
    dat3$sex <- as.factor(dat3$sex)

all.equal(dat3, dat2) #just to show both method 1 and 2 give the same data frame

#step 2
dat4 <- dat2[rep(seq_len(nrow(dat2)), dat2$n), 1:5]
rownames(dat4) <- 1:nrow(dat4)
dat4
```

I assume this is a common problem as when you want to take a table from an article and reproduce it, it requires some unpacking.  I am finding myself doing this more and more and want to make sure I'm being efficient.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a one-liner.

```
dat2 <- ddply(dat, 1:4, summarize, sex = c(rep('m', m), rep('f', f)))
```

Answer (score 5):

And here's a base R one-liner.

```
dat2 <- cbind(dat[c(rep(1:nrow(dat), dat$m), rep(1:nrow(dat), dat$f)),1:4],
              sex=c(rep("m",sum(dat$m)), rep("f", sum(dat$f))))
```

Or, a little more generally:

```
d1 <- dat[,1:4]
d2 <- as.matrix(dat[,5:6])
dat2 <- cbind(d1[rep(rep(1:nrow(dat), ncol(d2)), d2),], 
              sex=rep(colnames(d2), colSums(d2)))
```

Answer (score 3):

Given that nobody has posted a `data.table` solution (as suggested in the original question)

```
library(data.table)
DT <- as.data.table(dat)   
DT[,list(sex = rep(c('m','f'),c(m,f))), by=  list(i1,i2,i3,i4)]
```

Or, even more succinctly

```
DT[,list(sex = rep(c('m','f'),c(m,f))), by=  'i1,i2,i3,i4']
```

Comment: Can `c(m,f)` (and `list(i1,i2,i3,i4)`) be modified to refer to a variable containing the column names?  For example, rather than the m and f columns, what if I have 100 columns (say Var0 through Var99) and didn't want to type out the name of each column.

Answer (score 2):

I would use `melt` for the first step and `ddply` for the second.

```
library(reshape2)
library(plyr)
d <- ddply( 
  melt(dat, id.vars=c("i1","i2","i3","i4"), variable.name="sex"), 
  c("i1","i2","i3","i4","sex"), 
  summarize, 
  id=rep(1,value) 
)
d$id <- cumsum(d$id)
```

Comment: I like it better than my approach by far.  If no one comes up with anything more efficient (less code writing that is not speed) I'll mark this one as the correct answer. +1

Comment: I'm marking this as correct.  I don't think anyone can beat this amount of code.

Comment: I stand corrected.  Impressive results.  Way less code than I have been using.