# Converting contingency tables with counts to two-column data tables with frequency columns

Tags: r, data.table

I would like to enter a frequency table into an R `data.table`.

The data are in a format like this:

```
          Height
Gender    3      35
m       173     125
f       323     198
```

... where the entries in the table (173, 125, etc.) are counts.

I have a 2 by 2 table, and I want to turn it into two-column `data.table`.

The data is from a study of birds who nest at a height. The question is whether different genders of the bird prefer certain heights.

I thought the frequency table should be turned into something like this:

```
    Gender height   N
      m      3     173
      m      35    125
      f      3     323
      f      35    198
```

but now I'm not so sure. Some of the models I want to run need every case itemized.

Can I do this conversion in R? Ideally, I'd like a way to switch back and forth between the two formats.

Comment: Can you show what the input looks like? Share the output of `dput(input_table)`at the end of your question.

Comment: I haven't really made a data table yet, aside from the one I described above:

`structure(list(sex = c("f", "f", "m", "m"), height = c(3, 35, 
3, 35), freq = c(323, 198, 173, 125)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))`

Comment: You might want to refer to [How to convert a frequency table into a vector of values?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/15574/how-to-convert-a-frequency-table-into-a-vector-of-values).

Comment: BTW, I am using data.table on purpose, as other parts of the book need it.

Comment: What you have posted in your question is the your desired output, no? I was asking for the "2 by 2 table" that you mentioned.

Comment: ... or [reshaping data (a faster way)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9935755/reshaping-data-a-faster-way?rq=1).

Comment: No: What I have posted in my question was my first attempt at making a data table. I used the edit() function to do it, and I'm not completely sure how the third varible got the attribute `freq`. I was trying to use the `count` function; maybe that did it.

What I have in my question is a data tavle with four lines. It cane from a 2 by two in a book

Comment: _Would I be better off with a data table having (323+198+173+125) rows?_ - "Better off" in which respect? And how is this related to your title? Cheers

Comment: I previously found both of the pages referred to above, but they didn’t help. If I’m entering data from a book (like the second page discusses), it seems I’d enter it in the best way to start with. I’m asking if the best way a 4-row data table, or should I enter it as a very long table, with one row per case?

Comment: This is a standard kind of structure called `table`  ... you should be able to convert your data using as.table() ... for example the occupationalStatus data set.

Comment: Better off, as in which format lends itself to R’s analysis methods, like testing whether there is a height preference based on gender? In looking at the ways that could be answered, I found a lot of functions in various packages, and their documentation never mentioned support if a free variable.

Comment: "R’s analysis methods" is vague. Please try to be more explicit exactly what you want to achieve.

Comment: Take the t-test function, documented at https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.5.2/topics/t.test. Nothing about using a freq variable there.

Comment: I wouldn't use a ttest for count data but you can use loglin.

Comment: Yes, @Elin, you are right. Thanks for all the help.

Comment: Due to my intermittent connection, it took me rather a lot longer to respond to things that I would have liked. I hope you'll read my answer at the bottom, which may ungarble some of this and allow you to remove the negative ratings.

Answer (score 1):

Based on a review of ?table.

1. Make a data frame (x) with columns for Gender, Height, and Freq  which would be your N value.
2. Convert that to a table by using

```
tabledata <- xtabs(Freq ~ ., x)
```

There are a number of base functions that can work with this kind of data, which is obviously much more compact than individual rows.

Also from ?loglin  this example using table.

```
 loglin(HairEyeColor, list(c(1, 2), c(1, 3), c(2, 3)))
```

Comment: Quite elegant, that. I was easily able to generate
```
> tabledata
      HEIGHT
GENDER   3  35
     f 323 198
     m 173 125```

Comment: I'd love to correct the comment above, but I've not got permissions anymore. What I wanted to say was---------->

Quite elegant, that `xtabs`. I was easily able to generate a perfect 2 by 2 table. I'm putting this one in the toolbox.

`loglin` is still challenging me, but I'm still not 100% on why I need that heavy of a statistical hammer. I'm looking to see if there's a gender difference for the two heights, which feels like a vanilla ² analysis. I'll think on it more.

Comment: You can get a chisquare by doing summary() around a table object.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, everybody (@simon and  @Elin) for the help. I thought I was conducting a poll that would get answers like "start with the 4-row version" or "start with the 719-row version" and you all have given me an entire toolbox of ways to move from one to the other. It's really great, informative, and way more than the inquiry deserves.

I unquestionably need to work harder and get more explicit in forming a question. I see by the -3 rating that this boondoggle has earned, crystallizing the fact that I'm not adding anything to the knowledge base, so will delete the question in order to keep future searchers from finding this. I've had a bad run recently with my questions, and as a former teacher of the year, writer of five books, and PhD statistician, it's extremely embarrassing to have been on Stack Exchange for as long as I have, and stand here with one reputation point. One. That means that my upvotes of your answers don't count for a thing.

That reputation point should be scarlet colored.

---

Here's what I was getting at:
In a book, a common way to express data is in a 2×2 table:

```
             Height 
 Gender     3     35 
    M      173   175 
    F      323   198
```

My tic-tac-sized mind sees two ways of entering that into a data table:

```
require(data.table)
GENDER <- c("m","m","f","f")
HEIGHT <- c(3, 35, 3, 35)
N <- c(173, 125, 323, 198)
SANDFLIERS <-data.table(GENDER, HEIGHT, N)
```

That gives the four-line flat-file/tidy representation of the data:

```
   GENDER HEIGHT   N
1:      m      3 173
2:      m     35 125
3:      f      3 323
4:      f     35 198
```

The other option is to make a 719-row data table with 173 male@3ft, 125 male@35 feet, etc. It's not too bad if you use the `rep()` command and build your table columns carefully. I hate doing arithmetic, so I leave some of these numbers bare and untotaled.

```
# I need 173+125 males, and 323+198 females.
# One c(rep()) for "m", one c(rep() for "f", and one c() to merge them
gender <- c(c(rep("m", 173+25)), c(rep("f",(323+198))))

# Same here, except the c() functions are one level 'deeper'. I need two
# sets for males (at heights 3 and 35, 173 and 125 of each, respectively)
# and two sets for females (at heights 3 and 35, 323 and 198 respectively)
heights <-c(c(c(rep(3, 173)), c(rep(35,25))), c(c(rep(3, 323)), c(rep(35,198))))
```

which, when merged into a `data.table` gives 719 rows, one for each observed bird.

```
  1:      m       3
  2:      m       3
  3:      m       3
  4:      m       3
  5:      m       3
 ---               
715:      f      35
716:      f      35
717:      f      35
718:      f      35
719:      f      35
```

Now that I have the data in two formats, I start looking for ways to do plots and analyses.

I can get a mosaic plot using the 719-row version, but you can't see it because of my 1-point reputation

```
mosaicplot(table(sandfliers), COLOR=TRUE, margin, legend=TRUE)
```

[Mosaic Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Hpgx.png)

and you can get a balloon plot using the 4-row version

[Balloon Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LEBpB.png)

So my question was, for those of you with lots and lots of experience with this sort of thing, do you find the 4-row or the 719-row tables more common. I can change from one to the other, but that's more code to add to the book (again I hear my editor, "You're teaching statistics, not R").

So, as I said at the top, this was just an informal poll on whether one is used more often than the other, or whether beginners are better off with one.

Comment: There's no need for embarrassment. I know quite a few statisticians who are experts in all sorts of things, but not R. For myself, I certainly know more about programming than I do about statistics. Nevertheless, when I was learning R (and even now, from time to time), I found that efficiently manipulating the data from the form in which I had it into the form that library functions required was much more difficult than using the functions themselves. I'll happily edit your question into the form I think most answerers were hoping for, and "+1" your question, if you'd like.

Comment: Every little bit helps. Thanks, @Simon.

Comment: I hope you see the second half of this answer. I added it to explain what was in my head.

Comment: I've tried editing your question to make it specific enough to answer. I expect your additional question that seeks an "informal poll" of whether one format is used rather than another would likely be voted closed for seeking opinions rather than definitive factual answers. Being able to convert the format back and forth very easily means you can accommodate any data format required by any model or formula you want to use.

Comment: I've thought about this exact issue a lot. If you look at the sample data that comes with default r you see a number of table objects.  These are sometimes called cubes in proprietary formats.  That's all fine but what if we have an actual survey with 40 variables, some numeric, some factor.  Is it going to make sense to create the crosstabs to store that? Clearly  there is a tipping point in terms of size/memory.  But it  really depends on how many identical observations you have

Answer (score 0):

This is in the form of a contingency table. It isn't easy to enter directly into R but it can be done as follows (based on http://cyclismo.org/tutorial/R/tables.html):

```
> f <- matrix(c(173,125,323,198),nrow=2,byrow=TRUE)
> colnames(f) <- c(3,35)
> rownames(f) <- c("m","f")
> f <- as.table(f)
> f
    3  35
m 173 125
f 323 198
```

You can then create a count or frequency table with:

```
> as.data.frame(f)
  Var1 Var2 Freq
1    m    3  173
2    f    3  323
3    m   35  125
4    f   35  198
```

The [R Cookbook](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Manipulating_data/Converting_between_data_frames_and_contingency_tables/) gives a short function to convert to a table of cases (i.e. a long list of the individual items), as follows:

```
> countsToCases(as.data.frame(f))
```

... where:

```
# Convert from data frame of counts to data frame of cases.
# `countcol` is the name of the column containing the counts
countsToCases <- function(x, countcol = "Freq") {
    # Get the row indices to pull from x
    idx <- rep.int(seq_len(nrow(x)), x[[countcol]])

    # Drop count column
    x[[countcol]] <- NULL

    # Get the rows from x
    x[idx, ]
}
```

... thus you can convert the data to the format needed by any analysis method from any starting format.

(EDIT)

Another way to read in the contingency table is to start with text like this:

```
> ss <- " 3      35
+ m       173     125
+ f       323     198"
> read.table(text=ss,row.name=1)
   X3 X35
m 173 125
f 323 198
```

Instead of using `text =`, you can also use a file name to read the table from (for example) a CSV file.

Comment: Yes, exactly. I started with the table you show. I have two choices on how to enter that into R: the 4-row way I showed in my question, and the very long table you showed above. I know that both can be made, and that one can be turned into the other. What I don’t know is the advice to give readers. If I’m going to do a t-test comparing m heights vs f heights, which is the best way to make the data.table to start with? I looked at a lot of packages that do the test I want, but none mention frequency variables, so I thought maybe entering the data in the long format is better.